# Default StorageClass set up for Docker EE Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ingress

We're using Docker EE Kubernetes on-prem set up and noticed that cluster(s) don't have default StorageClass set up. To the best of my knowledge this is supposed to be set up during install/set up, but not done here.

I am aware of steps and have YAML in place to create a PV and StoageClass but trying to understand if there are any best practices and 'right' approach to set that up?

I came across [nfs-volume](https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/kubernetes/storage/use-nfs-volumes/#exposing-nfs-shares-as-a-cluster-object) but still not clear if we need a separate NFS drive/server, or can we use one of the nodes for creating the StorageClass(SC)?

Also we don't want the SC to be available for other namespaces or pods as I need to set up SC as a pre-requisite for installing an Ingress Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that there is no specific 'default' storageclass(SC) type for Docker EE or others, it depends on the requirement and specific to Kubernetes provider(s). I went ahead and created a sc with 'local' provisioner type.